# Reconnecting pc to domain?

Tags: windows, dns

Computer (part of domain) has been out of use for 5 weeks.

Will PC be able to connect to domain if I turn it on now.

If not why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A computer connected to the domain will stay connected until it is removed.  You will have no issues turning it on and using it.